# Padding not working after menu sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap menu bottom padding not working after sticky, but top padding working good. It's working after refresh the page. Only after sticky menu not working bottom padding.

My default menu code-

```
.floridabt-nav{
   padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Sticky code-

```
.is-sticky .floridabt-nav{
   background: #ddd;
   z-index: 99;
   padding: 0;
}
```

I used this sticky js plugin https://github.com/garand/sticky

Thanks

Comment: You can use `position: sticky;`, it has pretty good support.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb Not yet bro.

Comment: where i'll use position: sticky;

Comment: Neither IE11 nor Edge support position sticky yet, not sure if you can afford to ignore those browsers. I wish I could...

Comment: @PatrickHund, _everyone_ should ignore ie and edge.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, support is better than it was: https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb Agreed, but not complete.